# Display images from Drawable folder using Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I want to load image from Drawable folder using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/) (NOSTRA my code is below

```
imgLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imgLoader.init(new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build());
```

Now i am loading image in wallImage (ImageView) below is my code

```
imgLoader.displayImage("drawable://" + result, wallImage);
```

my problem is, it is taking to much time to load image. Can anybody give me solution what should I have to do ?

Comment: Why don't you use the native approach, as UIL developers recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Imgloader.displayImage("drawable://" + result, wallImage);
```

this method is not recommending for loading the images in drawable... You should use native method as Vigbyor as suggested

```
imageview.setImageResources(res id);
```

Comment: If I use setImageResource won't it mean that I'm not using the options from universal image loader?

Comment: @RED_ i think it wil1 take default options

Comment: To future SO users: This week I started investigating many posts on internet about best ways to load images. I experimented a little bit and manage to get a way to load images located in drawable folders "asyncly". It is faster than  `Imgloader.displayImage("drawable://" + result, wallImage);` (tested with a 2560x1080px image http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/A-Stormtrooper-lost-in-the-desert.-2560x1080-Imgur.jpg and drawing it inside an image view 100*100). After doing that, I discovered `universal image loader`, which I think is great, but it has the problem you mention before.

Comment: I will try to make a pull merge as soon as I understand how Universal Image Loader works under the hood. Until then, you may want to see the code I did. Sorry for the mess in advance, but you only need to call this: `BitmapUtil.loadResourceAsyncWithCache(context,
   imageView, drawableId, reqWidth, reqHeight,
   false)`. The code is here: https://github.com/gian1200/Android-Util.